# Align a union to 16 byte boundary in x86.

Tags: c, gcc

I got this union, which I am trying to align to 16 byte boundary, using gcc 4.8.

```
typedef union {
 unsigned long long int ud[(1<<6)/8];
 long long int d[(1<<6)/8];
 unsigned int uw[(1<<6)/4];
 int w[(1<<6)/4];
 short uh[(1<<6)/2];
 unsigned short int h[(1<<6)/2];
 unsigned char ub[(1<<6)/1];
 char b[(1<<6)/1];
} vector_t;
```

I tried

```
vector_t __attribute__ ((aligned(16))) t;
```

But it is not working. Address of variable t in stack is not aligned to 16 bytes.

I was able to align it using __declspec align(16) in VS 10. Please let me know what is the way to do this in gcc.

Comment: You mean 16-bit boundary? I think it is not possible to half-word align an `unsigned long long` or any other data type greater than 4 bytes in size. I might be wrong, though.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword `__attribute__` allows you to specify special attributes of `struct` and `union` types when you *define* such types. You need to do

```
typedef union __attribute__ ((aligned(16))) {
  unsigned long long int ud[(1<<6)/8];
  long long int d[(1<<6)/8];
  unsigned int uw[(1<<6)/4];
  int w[(1<<6)/4];
  short uh[(1<<6)/2];
  unsigned short int h[(1<<6)/2];
  unsigned char ub[(1<<6)/1];
  char b[(1<<6)/1];
} vector_t;
```

Comment: Exactly, you need the keyword for the definition :-)

Comment: In other words, the attribute is part of the type - not part of a particular instance of it